# Print_r array problem

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("coockie");

    $filename ="excelreport.xls";
    $contents = "date \t ip \t visits \t \n";

    $result=mysql_query("select * from test");

    $mydate='';
    $myip='';
    $visits='';

    while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $mydate.=explode(",", $data['date']);
        $myip.=explode(",", $data['ip']);
        $visits.=$data['visits'];

    }

    print_r($mydate);

    //header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    //echo $contents;
?>
```

`$mydate` is outputted as string `Array`. I need it outputted like array of values. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clearify - there is a recursion in your question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing string concatenation operator `.=`

```
$mydate.=explode(",", $data['date']);
```

`explode` gives you an array, and with `.=` it's converted to string `Array`. The proper way is to use `[]` operator

```
$mydate=array();
$myip=array();
$visits='';

while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $mydate[]=explode(",", $data['date']);
    $myip[]=explode(",", $data['ip']);
    $visits.=$data['visits'];

}

print_r($mydate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `var_dump` instead of `print_r`. At least for debugging purposes.

```
var_dump($mydate);
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good suggestion. It works just like `print_r` but will also show you the types of all data.

Comment: Plus that it can prettyformat the output as readable html, and it will recursively dump the members (privates as well) of all types of objects.